# Karaf auto polling for latest version

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I am a new bee in the world of OSGi and using Apache Karaf for my application. I know how to create/work with bundle and features. I have my A.jar, which I have deployed in karaf_home/deploy folder and its working.

My actual requirement is, **I will update the jar version in our Maven repo and I want Karaf automatically poll that external repository for any updated version. If it finds any updated version is present, it will download and install it**.

If I can put the latest version (by some means) under karaf_home/deploy directory, Karaf consumes it automatically and working fine. I want to automate this download process from some external path (may be maven repo as mentioned earlier). *Is it possible at this level*?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this for a local repository and only for snapshot versions.
Just type dev:watch * in the karaf shell.

Then karaf will monitor the local maven repo for all artifacts currently deployed using the mvn: protocoll and that end in -SNAPSHOT for the version. If you then do mvn install on such a project karaf will automatically update the bundle.

Comment: This wouldn't be truly automated solution, as you still need to schedule a `mvn install` for the project and the project needs to reside in your system. Better schedule a `mvn depedency:get` for the required artifact. Also you want to double check if local repo for maven, and the local repo configured in `${karaf.etc}/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` matches